# Why can't jquery call it or access it ( $.fancybox.resize() )

Tags: jquery, ajax, fancybox

My problem is that I don't no why I get errors with these statements, wich are right off the [example-page](http://fancybox.net/blog) **tip 5**

in FF: Tijdstempel: 16-06-12 17:05:38
Fout: $.fancybox.showActivity is not a function
Bronbestand: http://woonbel.nl/js/js.js
Regel: 28

```
$.fancybox.resize();
$.fancybox.showActivity();
```

and how is the returned ajax data handeld

```
$.fancybox(data) // (what does it do, or is the object itself used for storage?)
```

do you suppose to access it like this

```
returndata = $.fancybox.data.testdata;
```

[this is my testsite](http://www.woonbel.nl) click topleft corner!

**EDIT**
I found that the documentation does not follow the plugincode
apparently showactivity() has become showLoading();

Now I only have to look how $.fancybox(data) is supposed to work with the current plugin code. Suggestions would be great!

thanks, Richard

Comment: Did you include fancybox? `<script src="path.to.fancybox.js" .. />`

Comment: What kind of error you get? try to check your browser error console (Firebug is handy for such things).

Comment: Have you included jQuery **before** including fancybox: http://jquery.com

Comment: I edited my question so you can see for yourself

Comment: Not that we should have to dig around for it, but when I hit that page I get nothing, and blank source.

Comment: I do not understand what you are saying, because if I click the link, I go to my page, as far as digging around, it was more to show that fancybox or jquery indeed where getting loaded. aside from that, maybe it could be helpfull for some..

Comment: Yes, I could not open the page either. It's just a blank page.

Comment: I don't get that, maybe your browser javascript is to strict,

Comment: OK, I "guess" you are using a newer version of the plugin. Try showLoading in place of showActivity.

Comment: maybe it works now that I solved one problem, I edited my question

Comment: appology, I was working from my cache even when I was clearing the cache...will see what I can do about it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting those errors because you are using *fancybox v2.x* with options for *fancybox v1.3.x*. The example page you are referring http://fancybox.net/blog is for version 1.3.4

Fancybox v2.x options are new and not compatible with previous versions.

In your case, instead of using

```
$.fancybox.showActivity(); //v1.3.x
```

you should use

```
$.fancybox.showLoading(); //v2.x
```

.... and instead of

```
$.fancybox.resize(); //v1.3.x
```

you should use

```
$.fancybox.update(); //v2.x
```

Check http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#docs for the right set of options for the version you are using.

Comment: thanks, I was a little late connecting the dots. I also had a cache problem, thus I could not oversee all off the problems. Apparently, I have to fix some php errors also. If I need to update the form I should not use $.fancybox(data), because it completely overwrites the exsisting form or I will need to make a template, anyway thanks for the clarification!